# Binding issue over the Datatrigger in DataTemplate - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

**Objective**
My objective is to load the Control in `GridView`row based on the property in the viewmodel.

**Sample Code:**
Here is the sample xaml which I tried.

```
<ListView Margin="10" Name="lvUsers">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="gridview">
            <GridViewColumn Header="Type">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl>
                            <ContentControl.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsImage}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                <Setter.Value>                                                        
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="Text goes here"
                                                    Foreground="Red"/>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>

                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsImage}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Itemsource}"/>

                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </ContentControl.Style>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And my sample xaml.cs code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{    
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        List<myClass> mc = new List<myClass>();
        mc.Add(new myClass() { Itemsource = "test", IsImage = false });
        mc.Add(new myClass() { Itemsource = "test", IsImage = true });
        lvUsers.ItemsSource = mc;
    }     
}

class myClass
{
    public string Itemsource { get; set; }
    public bool IsImage { get; set; }
}
```

**Issue:**  `DataTriggers` are working as expected but the binding inside the `Triggers` is giving me Empty

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Itemsource}"/>
```

I am expecting the above line to display `test` in the respective row but it displaying `Empty` row.

Comment: "..based on the property in the viewmodel." You don't have a ViewModel

Comment: @Tyress This is just a sample code to make it simple and for better understanding of the issue.  Actual code is different from this one where I have the actual VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't figure out why the TextBlock's DataContext is null. Its probably due to the custom content template. But any how you can fix this by searching for the ContentControl ancestor type like this.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsImage}" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Itemsource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContentControl}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

This will fetch the data from the parent controls data binding.

**Edit**

It's because of ContentControl, you need to do content binding like - `<ContentControl Content="{Binding}">`. Then data context will be available as it is and `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Itemsource}"/>` will work.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsImage}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>                                                        
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="Text goes here"
                            Foreground="Red"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsImage}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Itemsource}"/>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Works.  Let me see for some time whether we are getting the exact issue before accepting this one.

Comment: Can you tell me where it should be binded.  Tried `Binding` in `ContentControl`.  No luck

Comment: If that is the case, Do you know how the `Datatriggers` inside the `ContentControl` worked as expected?

Comment: Good questions! But no idea why :)

Comment: Possibly, `ContentControl.Style` is logically belongs to `ContentControl` but not Ancestor.  So, it has the content from its Ancestor `GridView`.  However, `TextBlock` is down the tree with `ContentControl` as a Ancestor.  Since the `ContentControl` doesnot have the content binded, `TextBlock` (child of ContentControl`) Datacontext comes as Empty I think.   Not sure.